# Mysql connection of two select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table (list) with list of names and second table(rec) with records of price referenced to id in first table.

Second table(rec) header looks like:

```
price|fk_id|what
```

I try to count sum of prices for all names in first table but divided by column **what**. What can contain: REPAIR and BUY
For example:

```
NAME |REPAIR|BUY
----------------
Name1|   120|340
Name2|    20|40
```

I know create sql to REPAIR:

```
SELECT z.name, COALESCE(SUM(zb.price), 0) AS REPAIR FROM list z
LEFT JOIN rec zb ON zb.fk_id = z.id AND zb.what = "repair" 
GROUP BY z.id
ORDER BY z.id
```

How I can connect second column BUY?
I try to:

```
SELECT z.name, COALESCE(SUM(zb.price), 0) AS REPAIR, col2.BUY FROM list z
JOIN (
...The same select with zb.what = buy..
) as col2
LEFT JOIN rec zb ON zb.fk_id = z.id AND zb.what = "repair" 
GROUP BY z.id
ORDER BY z.id
```

but it not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't join with tables and columns that are only in a subquery. You would have to change the subquery so that it also returned `z.id`, and then then join `ON zb.fk_id = col2.id`. But you don't need a subquery, you can do it all in one query:

```
SELECT z.name, 
        COALESCE(SUM(IF(zb.what = "repair", zb.price, 0)), 0) AS repair,
        COALESCE(SUM(IF(zb.what = "buy", zb.price, 0)), 0) AS buy
FROM list AS z
LEFT JOIN rec AS zb ON zb.fk_id = z.id
GROUP BY z.id
ORDER BY z.id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, subqueries are too slow. :)